# How to calculate the percentage of a nested table architecture in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My current tables architecture is the following:

1. Card Table ( Parent table: `Card`)
2. Each card has one or many lists (Second child `lists`)
3. Each list has many tasks (third child `tasks`)
4. Whenever the user fill a task it will be filled in a separate table called (`user_tasks`)

So if you want to imagine it it's like a Tree
Card => many cards lists => many lists tasks.

### Card

ID | Name

### Lists

ID | Card_ID | Name

### Tasks

ID | Lists_Id | Card_Id | Title

### User Tasks

Id | Task_id | User_Id | Content

Now I need to write a query or a simple logic whatever it is that I can't figure out at all to calculate the progress of each card.

the card progress is calculated by how Lists the user completely filled.

Examples:

1. Card 1 has 3 lists each one has 4 tasks

User filled all tasks (4x3) in these lists the card progress will be 3/3.

2. Card 1 has 3 lists each one has 4 tasks

User filled all tasks in any 2 lists (4x2) the card progress will be 2/3

3. Card 1 has 3 lists each one has 4 tasks

User filled only 2 tasks in list 1 that contains 4 tasks the card progress will be 0/3

So to consider a list done of fulfilled the user has to fill all its tasks.
can someone guide me on how to do the logic of a nested tables architecture to get the cards to progress, please?

So I expect the output to be as the following in any way:

```
{
   card_id: 1,
   total_lists: 10
   total_filled: 3
}
```

and goes on, on all cards in the databse...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: how to provide them? you need the schema? @GMB

Comment: Just a few, representative rows from each table, along with the corresponding result - all as tabular text (SO has nice options format tables).

Comment: @GMB okay I did a few edits

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below query

```
SELECT target.cardid as 'card_id', target.total as 'total_lists', IFNULL(progress.total,0) as 'total_filled'
FROM   (SELECT l.cardid, Count(l.id) total 
        FROM   lists l 
        GROUP  BY l.cardid) target
LEFT JOIN (SELECT l.cardid, userlist.userid, Count(userlist.listid) total 
                   FROM   lists l 
                          INNER JOIN (SELECT ut.userid, t1.listid, Count(ut.taskid) tcount 
                                      FROM   user_tasks ut 
                                             INNER JOIN tasks t1 ON t1.id = ut.taskid 
                                      GROUP  BY ut.userid, t1.listid) userlist --- STEP#1
                                  ON l.id = userlist.listid 
                          INNER JOIN (SELECT t.listid, Count(*) tcount 
                                      FROM   tasks t 
                                      GROUP  BY t.listid) tasklist --- STEP#2
                                  ON userlist.listid = tasklist.listid  AND userlist.tcount = tasklist.tcount --- STEP#3
                   GROUP  BY l.cardid, userlist.userid) progress  -- STEP#4
ON target.cardid = progress.cardid;
```

**Description:**

- `Step#1`: Determine the count of tasks per user_id and list_id
- `Step#2`: Determine the count of tasks per list_id for all lists
- `Step#3`: Filter records in `user_task` that does not have entries for all tasks in a list
- `Step#4`: Get list count in `user_task` that has entries for all tasks
- Finally, join the `target` and `progress` subqueries to fetch the final result.

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tAzoL49SSd2SJDK5k19a3/3

---

*Note:* Couple of observations

1. Ideally, table `tasks` should not have `cardid`, only `listid` must be present.
2. Can 2 different users work on the same card? In that case, in the result, you need to include the `userid` as well. Refer - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tAzoL49SSd2SJDK5k19a3/4

Comment: this seems more complicated than needed?  I think there only needs to be one subquery

Comment: @ysth, did tried my level best to simplify it. Not even able to do it with mysql 8 features. Would be great if you can you use this link, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tAzoL49SSd2SJDK5k19a3/3, and post a simplified answer, pls? Requirement is % of lists in user_tasks against total lists for a card and user. The list in user_tasks need to counted only if it has entries for all tasks in the list.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mHdQuhLY6QVoHkGyLrNPYE/2

Comment: @ysth Awesome!!! Can you please post this answer? Should help mba3gar

Comment: Thank you so much guys. but I didn't get your question what do you mean 2 different users can work on the same card? it's already included in users_tasks
do you recommend a better architecture for a simpler query?

Comment: @mba3gar, I was curious in your result you are showing the total_filled against a card_id. What if 1 user 's percent is 100 and another user is 50 for that card? Is it possible? If so should you not include the user_id in the result?

Comment: @mba3gar, Also I suggest you try ysh solution first. It is a lot simpler. If that works for you, kindly accept that answer. Would help people in the future.

Comment: Yea the question is already accepted. But the whole project is done on a user basis. 
Like there is an authentication before this query.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly simple.  To find all the lists with tasks and check if all their tasks are filled you do this:

```
select lists.id,
     count(tasks.id)=count(user_tasks.id) filled  
from lists
join tasks on tasks.lists_id=lists.id
left join user_tasks on user_tasks.task_id=tasks.id
group by lists.id
```

To report on the number of total and filled lists per card, you use that as a subquery (adding card_id to be able to look up lists by card):

```
select card.id,
    count(card_lists.id) as total_lists,
    sum(card_lists.filled) as total_filled
from card
join (
    select lists.id, lists.card_id,
        count(tasks.id)=count(user_tasks.id) filled  
    from lists
    join tasks on tasks.lists_id=lists.id
    left join user_tasks on user_tasks.task_id=tasks.id
    group by lists.id, lists.card_id
) card_lists on card_lists.card_id=card.id
group by card.id
```

If a task could be filled by more than one user, change `count(user_tasks.id)` to `count(distinct user_tasks.tasks_id)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was really helpful and I really owe you help <3 .